# Java Inner Class and Extend

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Home {

    public void getHomeDetails(){
        Rooms r = new Rooms();
        r.getRooms();
    }

    public class Rooms{
        public void getRooms(){
            System.out.println("20");
        }
    }
}



public class BigHome extends Home{

    public class Inner extends Home.Rooms{
        public void getRooms(){
            System.out.println("100");
        }
    }
}



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BigHome bigHome = new BigHome();
        bigHome.getHomeDetails(); // output:20 (Expecting 100)
    }

}
```

I have a class Home and its inner class Room which prints 20.
Another class named BigHome extends Home and its inner class.
But when I initiate BigHome in Main Class. I get output as 20 (I was expecting output as 100)

**How do I call function getRoom of the BigHome Class ?**

Comment: I'd try not to create sophisticated class inheritance constructs. They usually become a real PITA quite rapidly. Class inheritance should be used with care and only where really neccessary. (I know, this contradicts most textbooks out there, but most "common wisdom" about object orientation is plain wrong IMHO.) I'd recommend reading the introductory chapters of "Design Patterns" by E. Gamma et al to get a reasonable explanation of the principles of OO and why class inheritance should be treated with care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigHome does not have a bigHome.getHomeDetails(); method, so it uses the method in the Home class which uses home's rooms. What you can do is setup constructors for the 2 classes, and in these constructors, then setup which Room class you want to use. Like:

```
public class Home
{
    Rooms r;

    public Home()
    {
        r = new Rooms();
    }

    public void getHomeDetails()
    {
        r.getRooms();
    }

    public class Rooms
    {

        public void getRooms()
        {
            System.out.println("20");
        }
    }
}

class BigHome extends Home
{
    public BigHome()
    {
        r = new Inner();
    }

    public class Inner extends Home.Rooms
    {

        public void getRooms()
        {
            System.out.println("100");
        }
    }
}
```

Now Home and BigHome are both in charge of specifying which Rooms they want to use.

Another approach, which takes away from the whole concept of inheritance, is to override the getHomeDetails method in the BigHome class to set which rooms BigHome is using.

```
public void getHomeDetails()
{
    Inner.Rooms r = new Inner.Rooms();
    r.getRooms();
}
```

I would not advise on this though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by moving the construction of a new `Rooms` instance into another method in `Home`, which you would then override in `BigHome` to return a new `Inner` instance instead:

```
public class Home {
    public Rooms createRooms() {
        return new Rooms();
    }

    public void getHomeDetails(){
        Rooms r = createRooms();
        r.getRooms();
    }

    ...
}

public class BigHome extends Home{
    @Override
    public Rooms createRooms() {
        return new Inner();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the method `getHomeDetails()` as

```
public void getHomeDetails(){
    Rooms r = new Rooms();
    r.getRooms();
}
```

and you never override this in any subclass. As such it never changes that you call `getRooms()` on a `Room` object and it will therefor always print 20.

That `BigHome` contains another class which also implements a `getRooms()` method is irrelevant. That this new class is also called Rooms doesn't mean it's the same class. When you call `getHomeDetails()` only the first `Room` object nested within `Home` will be instantiated and `getRooms()` will be called on this object and not any other.

Answer (score 1):

`BigHome` does not have a `getRoom` method, there is a `getRooms` in `Rooms` and `Inner`.

If you create an instance of `BigHome.Inner` and call `.getRooms()`, it will call `BigHome.Inner.getRooms`.  If you create an instance of `Home.Rooms` and call `.getRooms()`, it will call `Home.Rooms.getRooms`.

The problem you are facing is that `getHomeDetails` is defined in the parent class, `Home` and not anywhere else.  It creates an instance of `Home.Rooms` because that is what the code says to do and thus the 20.

Try over-writing `getHomeDetails` in `Inner`:

```
public void getHomeDetails(){
    Inner.Rooms r = new Inner.Rooms();
    r.getRooms();
}
```

That should print "100" instead of "20".